# Set position for new window

Tags: asp.net, javascript

hello i open a new window with:

```
<a href ="javascript:NewWindow =window.open('Default.aspx', 'NewWindow' , 'width=400, height=450'); NewWindow.focus()">Hilfe</a>
```

at the moment the new window appears in the upper left corner. how can i set the position, so it appears somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By providing `top` and `left`:

```
window.open('Default.aspx', 'NewWindow' , 'top=100, left=100, width=400, height=450')
```