# JavaScript Window Open Options

Tags: javascript

I am using JavaScript as a popup. 
But what I'd like it to do is load the popped up page in a certain area, Specified by say an X & Y coordinate.

My current code is :

```
function openwindow()
    {
        window.open("index.php?dll=gallery&sub=upload","mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=660px,height=390px");
    }
```

Is this achievable and if so, How, based on the code I've supplied.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open#Position_and_size_features

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set position for new window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317144/set-position-for-new-window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the parameters top and left, e.g. `window.open("index.php?dll=gallery&sub=upload","mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=660px,height=390px,top=0,left=0");`

Having said that, managing popup windows can be troublesome. If it's not necessary for your application, I would simply create a DHTML dialog in your actual page, e.g. jQuery's dialog, [jqueryui.com/demos/dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog) .

Comment: That just seems to position the window.. What I'd like to do is go to a specific region of the opened page..?

Comment: In that case you you could scroll to a part of the page. I'd recommend a plug-in like the one from the jQuery plugin repository, http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo.

Comment: @nickyt why reference jQueryui clone site? just goto the real one... (http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Comment: @Neal. I didn't realize I had referenced a cloned site. My bad. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

In the 3rd parameter add a `left` and a `top`

Answer (score 1):

You can add `top=?px,left=?px` to your propperties. For example

```
function openwindow()
{
    window.open("index.php?dll=gallery&sub=upload","mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=660px,height=390px,top=100px,left=150px");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to position the popup on the screen, you can use the screenX and screenY properties when opening a window, like so:

```
window.open("index.php?dll=gallery&sub=upload", "mywindow", "menubar=1, resizable=1, width=660px, height=390px, screenX=80, screenY=300")
```